# routerlink and router.navigate

Tags: angular, difference, routerlink

I was reading that routerlink implicitly calls relativeTo whereas this.router.navigate doesn't.

Knowing this info, I still can't seem to make the below work.

The routerlink works and gives me the following address:

http://localhost/main/(aux:crypto/5a599f35af967b0017d1be6f/blogoutlet:steemblog:)

But:

this.router.navigate([{outlets: { 'blogoutlet' : ['steemblog']}}])

only gives:

http://localhost/main/(aux:crypto/5a599f35af967b0017d1be6f)

Everytime I am trying to change these paths I struggle to understand what is going on and it takes me ages to work it out.
Is there a simple rule to it that I can follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`[routerLink]`** can be used in html for  or  elements. This will navigate to the path created with **`params`** given to routerLink.

`this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedHero.id]);`

is used in your component.ts or services to navigate to particular component provideed in path.

Comment: but how do I make this.router.navigate route to the same path as the routerlink? I notice I forgot to add the routerlink which points to the same path, but doesn’t work. Should I use something lije: router.navigate ([‘../‘, {outlets: {‘blogoutlet’:[‘Steemblog’]}}])

Comment: you need to provide the .navigate with the relative path

Comment: y I struggle to understand what the relative path means and how to add it, I tried the relative path, but with relativepath this.route it didn’t wokr

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512/difference-between-relative-path-and-absolute-path-in-javascript

Comment: thnak u so much I will mark that as the answer, could I ask u to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227043/angular-5-docker-nginx-reverse-proxy-trying-to-be-in-development-mode-ng-serve

Comment: Ok let me check